# Shortest possible way to go from one corner of the city to opposite corner if a city has $n,m$ parallel roads from east - west & north -south?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Let us suppose there is one city which has $n$ parallel roads running East - West and $m$ parallel roads running North - South. Now let us take that the distance between every consecutive pair of parallel road is the same. Then my question is that what will be the number of shortest possible ways to go from one corner of the city to its diagonally opposite corner? So what would be the answer ?

I tried doing but its getting much complicated after solving it for $m$ & $n$.

[image]

Comment: Can you find the link to [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)? Try filling in the number of ways to each junction across the city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a "block" as a portion of a road between adjacent intersections.

If we are going from the northwest corner to the southeast corner, we have to move $(n-1)$ blocks south and $(m-1)$ blocks east. A total of $(n+m-2)$ blocks altogether.

We can choose which order we arrange our south block moves and our east block moves, but essentially we just have to pick which of the $(n+m-2)$ moves are going to be (say) east. That means selecting $(m-1)$ items from $(n+m-2)$, written as

$$ {n+m-2 \choose {m-1}}$$

and evaluating to

$$ \frac{(n+m-2)!}{[(n+m-2)-(m-1)]!\:(m-1)!}= \frac{(n+m-2)!}{(n-1)!(m-1)!}$$

As you can see it doesn't matter whether we are picking position for the "east" moves or the "south" moves - the result is symmetrical between the two options.

Answer (score 4):

$$n+m-2\choose m-1 $$
as you make $n+m-2$ steps and $m-1$ of these must be vertical, the rest horizontal

Comment: ... and the vertical/horizontal choices can be in any order

Comment: Also, equidistance is not needed, the roads should just be "parallel enough"

Comment: I guess there will be so many steps so it will be like (m+n-2)! ?